# How to set phone's alarm from program code in Android

Tags: android

I want to set phones alarm in phone.
Can anybody say how to do that?

I got the code from net, and try but the alram not set to phone.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent activate = new Intent(this, Alaram.class);
AlarmManager alarams ;
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, activate, 0);
alarams = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarams.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

In this code we are provide intent as `Alaram.class.`
Then what should be written in this `Alram.class` so that alarm will set to the mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is good for. It starts your code on a given Point, it doesn't set the phones ring tone.

If you want to set the Phones Alarm sound, this might be helpful ([from the standard Android Music Player](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/03fbe7dfb76315abf0abf76cdb33d643f4f595dc/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackActivity.java#L579)):

```
// Set the system setting to make this the current ringtone
MusicUtils.setRingtone(this, mService.getAudioId());
```

Comment: i wanna schedule an alarm in the future. i am building a todo application and add a function to be able to set the alarm for a particular task.. by taking its text and adding it as a label

Comment: Ya but I want to know how we can set an alarm through our code? Example when we want to fix an alarm with a note we can easily do that by opening phones alarm option. But I want to know through our code we give time and note as from TextView and is set to the phone. and when we open phones Alarm Clock we can see our seted alarm with note there.  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You are setting alarm time as current time in millisecond it will be exceed when the alarmmanager wake up....So,here i modified your code.check this it will work.That alaram will start after 5 seconds...i mean your Alaram activity will start within 5 seconds.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent activate = new Intent(this, Alaram.class);
AlarmManager alarams ;
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, activate, 0);
alarams = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarams.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis()+5000, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: i tried that still its not working.. i got this warning too http://i.imgur.com/WkluL.png

Comment: The problem is your class file Alaram which is you are mentioned in Intent.AlarmManager can't invoke activity.You should change the Class Alaram to Receiver.just extend Alaram class to BroadcastReceiver instead of extending Activity and implement onReceive() method.From that method you can invoke your activity which you want...

Comment: .I want to be Automaticaly Cancel Alarm after 1 hr..then how i can do this ?